# Angular flow.js multiple file added event is not triggering in windows machine [more than 2000 .pdf files]

Tags: angularjs, flow-js

I am using Angular Flow JS to upload the multiple pdf files. When I tried selecting 1700 pdf, it was working fine and .fileAdded event triggered, but when I tried to upload 2000+ pdf files, the .fileAdded event not at all triggered. This issue is happening in Windows machine only. In Mac, I tried to select 5000 pdf's and it worked fine, but not working in windows. Any help is appreciated!